# Unboxing List of lists as Data Frame columns elegantly

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains a file name with regular parts. I use a regex to parse this file name and store each part in its own column.

```
parse.file.name <- function(file.name="cc-nolabel-AEMNZ334_0009-loc-1317-407-6-39.png")
{

rfn <- regexec(pattern="cc-(.+?)-(.+?)-loc-(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)\\.png", text=file.name)
matchfn <- regmatches(file.name, rfn)
return(matchfn)
}

basic.features$parsed.filename <- parse.file.name(as.character(basic.features$filename))
```

`filename` contains values similar to the default parameter. I'm retrieving the individual values for each column like the following:

```
 basic.features$label <- unlist(lapply(basic.features$parsed.filename,
                                      function(pf) {
                                         return(unlist(pf)[2]) } ))
```

I feel that this is not an elegant way but couldn't manage to get individual values from the data frame column that contains list in each row easily. Is there a better way to do this?

If you like example data:

```
basic.features <- data.frame(filename=c("cc-nolabel-AEMNZ336_0009-loc-1003-1504-7-8.png", "cc-nolabel-AEMNZ335_0006-loc-1979-880-13-10.png", "cc-nolabel-AEMNZ333_0007-loc-941-263-8-8.png", "cc-nolabel-AEMNZ336_0014-loc-2011-24-4-4.png", "cc-nolabel-AEMNZ335_0013-loc-2087-644-66-41.png", "cc-nolabel-AEMNZ333_0013-loc-1531-374-12-23.png"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler if you use `sapply`:

```
basic.features$label <- sapply(basic.features$parsed.filename,function(x){x[2]})
```

However, if you want to turn your parsed values into a data.frame in one shot, you could do this:

```
DF <- data.frame(t(sapply(basic.features$parsed.filename,function(x){x})))
colnames(DF) <- c('filename','label','code1','code2','code3','code4','code5')

> DF
                                         filename   label         code1 code2 code3 code4 code5
1  cc-nolabel-AEMNZ336_0009-loc-1003-1504-7-8.png nolabel AEMNZ336_0009  1003  1504     7     8
2 cc-nolabel-AEMNZ335_0006-loc-1979-880-13-10.png nolabel AEMNZ335_0006  1979   880    13    10
3    cc-nolabel-AEMNZ333_0007-loc-941-263-8-8.png nolabel AEMNZ333_0007   941   263     8     8
4    cc-nolabel-AEMNZ336_0014-loc-2011-24-4-4.png nolabel AEMNZ336_0014  2011    24     4     4
5 cc-nolabel-AEMNZ335_0013-loc-2087-644-66-41.png nolabel AEMNZ335_0013  2087   644    66    41
6 cc-nolabel-AEMNZ333_0013-loc-1531-374-12-23.png nolabel AEMNZ333_0013  1531   374    12    23
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend doing this in three steps.

1. convert your list of vectors to a matrix by row-binding them:

   ```
   mat <- do.call(rbind, basic.features$parsed.filename)
   ```
2. Next, convert to a data frame

   ```
   df <- as.data.frame(mat, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   ```
3. Finally, convert characters to columns of correct type and name columns

   ```
   df[] <- lapply(df, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)
   names(df) <- c('filename', 'label', 'code1', 'code2', 'code3', 'code4', 'code5')
   ```

Comment: Too bad I can only select one answer. Thank you.